await for View button click in a model task
In my Swift app I have a popover that requests a yes/no decision from the user, like this:
var yesNoRequester: some View {
  VStack {
      Text("Do you like it"?)

    HStack {
      Button(action: {
        model.yesNoRequesterResult(result: false)
      }, label: {
        Text("No")
      })
      
      Button(action: {
        model.yesNoRequesterResult(result: true)
      }, label: {
        Text("Yes")
      })
    }
  }
}

Now in my model I am running a async function like this
func doSomething() async {
    await firstFunction()

    // here I popup the yesNoRequester by setting a 'isShowing' property

    // Now I want to await a button click of my yesNoRequester
    // and receive the user decision whether to proceed with secondFunction or not
    // How do I achieve that ???

    await secondFunction()
}

Can anybody show how to achieve await-ing a View Button click in my model function ?

Awaiting for the Button would be a threading mess but it is possible with a completion handler. Personally I would just split it in 2 parts have part one function that triggers triggers the question at the end then a part 2 function when the user makes a selection

I agree with @lorem ipsum, split doSomething() into two parts.
Do the await firstFunction() and the isShowing in doSomething().
Then, make your yesNoRequester into a real view,
eg struct YesNoView: View {...}. Have in it
.onDisappear{ Task {  await model.secondFunction() } },
where you do the secondFunction.

In your .task, store a continuation in a state and resume it from the button action.

There are several ways to solve this. One possible way is to work with a CheckedContinuation.
The following demo implementation shows you how to do this:
struct DecisionView: View {
    private let decisionHandler: (Bool) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Decision 1") {
                decisionHandler(true)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)

            Button("Decision 2") {
                decisionHandler(false)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }

    init(_ decision: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler = decision
    }
}

The code for the integration could look like this:
@MainActor
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var isWorkPending = false
    @Published private(set) var isDecisionRequired = false
    @Published private(set) var decision: Bool?

    private var decisionContinuation: CheckedContinuation<Bool, Never>?

    deinit {
        if decisionContinuation != nil {
            fatalError("deinit without making a necessary decision")
        }
    }

    func onDecision(_ decision: Bool) {
        guard let decisionContinuation else {
            fatalError("Multiple decisions are not supported")
        }
        self.decisionContinuation = nil
        decisionContinuation.resume(returning: decision)
    }

    func someAsyncWork() async {
        guard decisionContinuation == nil else {
           fatalError("Multiple parallel calls to someAsyncWork are not supported")
        }

        isWorkPending = true
        defer {
            isWorkPending = false
        }

        print("starting async work")

        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))

        isDecisionRequired = true
        decision = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            decisionContinuation = continuation
        }
        isDecisionRequired = false

        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))

        print("async work done")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Start") {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.someAsyncWork()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .disabled(viewModel.isWorkPending)

            if viewModel.isDecisionRequired {
                DecisionView {
                    viewModel.onDecision($0)
                }
            }

            Text("Running: \(viewModel.isWorkPending)")

            if let decision = viewModel.decision {
                Text("Decision: \(decision)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

The someAsyncWork corresponds to your doSomething method.
In a real implementation, of course, you should not make any fatalError calls, this is just to demonstrate where you need to be careful.
If you have a somewhat more complex case where, for example, several calls waiting for the same decision can be made in parallel, then I would rather recommend a publish-subscriber pattern using Combine.
